# Composer 2.2 gives error on using PHP below 7.3 when it is using 7.3 but shouldnt need it anyway

Tags: php, composer-php, centos7, laravel-6

On CentOS 7 (company boxes so cannot change). Laravel builds stopped working last week with Composer 1.
Upgraded to Composer 2.3 and upgraded to PHP 7.3.
Began getting the following:

'Connecting to a secure proxy using curl is not supported on PHP versions below 7.3.0.'

Which is confusing because 7.3 is installed and confirmed that composer was using it.

Assumed the issue is actually the CURL version (have 7.29, 7.5 supports secure curl) so installed Composer 2.2 which supports PHP < 7.3.

But now getting the same error:
'Connecting to a secure proxy using curl is not supported on PHP versions below 7.3.0.'

Which is confusing because Composer 2.2 does not require PHP 7.3

**Output of composer diagnose:**

```
$ composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: WARNING
require.tymon/jwt-auth : exact version constraints (1.0.0-rc.5) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Connecting to a secure proxy using curl is not supported on PHP versions below 7.3.0.
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL                                                                                                                                                 
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Connecting to a secure proxy using curl is not supported on PHP versions below 7.3.0.                                                                 
Checking HTTP proxy: FAIL                                                                                                                                                                      
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Connecting to a secure proxy using curl is not supported on PHP versions below 7.3.0.                                                                 
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL                                                                                                                                                           
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Connecting to a secure proxy using curl is not supported on PHP versions below 7.3.0.                                                                 
Checking disk free space: OK                                                                                                                                                                   
Checking pubkeys:                                                                                                                                                                              
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642                                                                                          
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952                                                                                           
OK                                                                                                                                                                                             
Checking composer version: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Connecting to a secure proxy using curl is not supported on PHP versions below 7.3.0.
Composer version: 2.2.2
PHP version: 7.3.33
PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
cURL version: 7.29.0 libz 1.2.7 ssl NSS/3.53.1
zip: extension present, unzip present, 7-Zip not available
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? I'm dead in the water on builds.

Thanks

CentOS 7, Behind Corporate proxy

Comment: _"upgraded to PHP 7.3"_ Sounds like you left 7.2 installed and composer is still using it. Post the output of `composer diagnose`.

Comment: I verified it was using 7.3 but should not need it anyway. Adding composer diagnose output to post.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9314) _"curl needs the CURL_VERSION_HTTPS_PROXY feature (added in curl 7.52.0, Dec 2016). This constant was added in PHP 7.3 which allows checking for this feature."_ So it looks like the wording "not supported on PHP versions below 7.3.0" isn't quite accurate and should maybe be "not supported on cURL versions below 7.52.0." Did you install PHP from source?

Comment: Installed PHP with yum. I'm concerned about installing cURL 7.5 on CentOS 7.

Comment: You must be using a 3rd party repo for PHP (probably Remi?), as Centos 7 normally comes w/ PHP 5.4. You may have to downgrade to PHP 7.2.

Comment: Composer 2.2.2 is pretty outdated (nearly two years old), even Composer 2.5.8 (which is some months old) has support for PHP 7.2. But nevertheless, PHP 7.2 is horribly outdated. Even 7.3 is out of support since nearly two years. Please try to update your infrastructure

Comment: Also, see https://curl.se/docs/vuln-7.29.0.html: "curl version 7.29.0 was released on February 6 2013" - you shouldn't use that version anymore, according to the long list of vulnerabilities. Some of them are known and fixed since more than ten years!

Comment: Well aware of this system being outdated that is why it was stated at the beginning of the post. This is a legacy system for a few internal Web Applications.

Comment: Downgraded PHP to 7.2 and still receiving the same error.

Comment: Obviously. If the error tells you to use PHP 7.3 or later, and the constant that should be used has been added to cURL v7.52, you should use PHP 7.3 or later **and** cURL 7.52 or later

Comment: Composer 2.2 is supposed to support < 7.3. So not so obvious.

Comment: Was able to back out to Composer 1 and get a build. Tedious. Code is being migrated in a couple months but I'm freezing builds on this server. Thank God.
Thanks for the input.

Comment: I appreciate you are not allowed to rebuild the server (i.e. upgrade to a later version of Centos) but could you install Docker? You could Dockerise your app and run the latest versions of everything inside a container.

Comment: We have some containers set up for other web apps using ubuntu. We are currently transitioning to an internal cloud solution. I'm just needing to be able to do some maintenance and prep work for the changeover. Hoping things can hold together a little while longer.

Comment: "Composer 2.2 is supposed to support < 7.3" - PHP itself is not the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though Composer 2.2 supports PHP 7.2 cURL 7.52 is required.
CentOS 7 uses cURL 7.29.
Abandoned attempting to use Composer 2.2 to avoid a cURL update on CentOS 7